# Styling a default CSS class only in a div (example only bold in "div1")

Tags: css

when i use this:

```
b, strong { color: black;}
```

It applies to the whole website.
I want to set the black color only in a div named "div1", how can i do it?

- my div's default class name is "sidereportleft", i've applied this code, but still not working:

http://pastebin.com/JA5JXuNe

Comment: `b, strong { color: black;}` is a bad example because black is default color , you should check if HTML is valid first : https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your div has a class of `div1`, you could do it easily by:

```
.div1 b, 
.div1 strong {
    color: #000;
}
```